# Cannot compile glossary entry containing accented character

Tags: citing, compiling, glossaries

## Directory contents

```
.
├── Makefile
└── template.tex
```

## `Makefile`

```
all: make_pdflatex make_glossaries make_pdflatex make_pdflatex
make_pdflatex:
        pdflatex template.tex
make_glossaries:
        makeglossaries template.glo
```

## `template.tex` contents

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{T\"UV}
{
  name={T\"UV},
  description={Technischer \"UberwachungsVerein, translated to Technical Inspection Association. Internationally active, independent service companies from Germany and Austria that test, inspect and certify technicak systems, facilities and objects of all kinds in order to minimize hazards and prevent damages}
}


\begin{document}

   \gls{T\"UV}

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

## Issue

When I try to run `make all` I get the following error:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted. 
> \unhbox l.10 }

However, when I replace the `\"U` character with a regular, unaccented `U` the `make all` works.

How can I include the accented `\"U` character in my glossary entry and still have a successful compilation? Thanks...

Comment: Is this any help: [glossary with diacritic marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461428)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `\newglossaryentry` should be a simple identifier consisting of printable ASCII characters only.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{TUV}
 {
  name={T\"UV},
  description={Technischer \"UberwachungsVerein, translated to 
    Technical Inspection Association. Internationally active, 
    independent service companies from Germany and Austria that test, 
    inspect and certify technicak systems, facilities and objects of all
    kinds in order to minimize hazards and prevent damages
  },
 }


\begin{document}

\gls{TUV} \gls{TUV}

%\clearpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. So I guess the answer is that I cannot use special characters in the identifier.